# point belong to all tangents of $xe^x$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Given a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ as : $f(x)=xe^{-x}$, it graph is $(C)$.

**Question** : are there any point belong to all the tangents of $(C)$ ?

---

This is a part from a generalized problem : $f_{\lambda} (x)=(x+\lambda) e^{-x} $ and it graph is $(C_{\lambda})$.

But, is it correct ? I mean, are there any such points ?

Comment: Where is the $\lambda$ used in the definition of $f_\lambda$? Why does the title mention $xe^x$ and not $xe^{-x}$?

Comment: This question seems to be very foggy: on a given point on the graph of a derivable function there is one uinque tangent to that graph *on that point*, so the question makes no sense...

Comment: how about it now ?I have changed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point common to all the tangents of $C$, whether on the curve or not. The tangent line at $x=a$ is $y=(e^{-a}-ae^{-a})x+a^2e^{-a}.$ For $a=1$, this is horizontal at $e^{-1}$. For $a=0,$ this is $y=x$. These intersect at $(e^{-1},e^{-1})$ so if there is a common point, this is it. It is not on the tangent at $a=0.5$

Answer (score 2):

For a function $f$ the tangent at $(a, f(a))$
is
$\frac{y-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a)$
or $y = (x-a)f'(a) + f(a)
$.

If there is a point that all these tangents pass through,
then the set of equations

$\begin{align}
y &= (x-a)f'(a) + f(a)\\
y &= (x-b)f'(b) + f(b)\\
\end{align}
$

should have the same solution $(x, y)$
for any $a$ and $b$.

Subtracting them,
$0 = x(f'(a)-f'(b))-a f'(a) + b f'(b) + f(a)-f(b)$
or 
$$x = \frac{-a f'(a) + b f'(b) + f(a)-f(b)}{f'(b)-f'(a)}$$
and 
$y$ is messier.

Requiring $x$ to be the same for all $a$ and $b$
would result in a differential equation involving $f$
that would be gotten by letting $b \to a$.
I'm not willing to do this,
so I'll work with the supplied function.

For $f(x) = x e^{-x}$,
$f'(x) = -x e^{-x} +  e^{-x} = (1-x) e^{-x}$,
so

$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{-a(1-a)e^{-a} + b(1-b)e^{-b} + a e^{-a}-be^{-b}}{(1-b)e^{-b}-(1-a)e^{-a} }\\
 &= \frac{(a-a(1-a))e^{-a} + (b(1-b)-b)e^{-b}}{(1-b)e^{-b}-(1-a)e^{-a} }\\
 &= \frac{a^2e^{-a} - b^2e^{-b}}{(1-b)e^{-b}-(1-a)e^{-a} }\\
\end{align}
$

For $a=0$
this is
$\frac{-b^2e^{-b}}{(1-b)e^{-b}-1 }$

Since this is not the same for all $a$ and $b$,
there is no such point.